# Unexpected exception executing action org.drools.common.TruthMaintenanceSystem$LogicalRetractCallback@37313731

Tags: drools

I have a class A.  At creation I declare type B and inserting the instances of B into working memory whenever instances of A gets created.

For each instance of A, there is an instance of B.

Problem:
There is a rule that retracts a few instances of class A.

I am getting the exception

```
org.drools.RuntimeDroolsException: Unexpected exception executing action org.drools.common.TruthMaintenanceSystem$LogicalRetractCallback@37313731
```

in the rule that retracts the instances of A.

I am not able to understand what could be possible reasons for the error.

We recently upgraded the drools version from 5.3.0 to 5.6.0

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: Add all relevant rules, i.e., a set of rules reproducing the error. Add the Java code of A and B, as far as it is relevant for reproducing the error. Add the full stack dump.